# Condition for vector to have redundant coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Consider the vector $V\in\mathbb{R}^6$:

$$V=\begin{bmatrix} -1&1&-1&-1 \\ -1&1&1&-1 \\ -1&-1&1&-1 \\ -1&1&1&1 \\ -1&-1&1&1 \\ -1&-1&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$$

I'd like to find values of $a,b,c,d$ such that $V$ has exactly $4$ different coordinates (among its 6 coordinates). I am not sure if it is possible with $a,b,c,d$ all different but I am stuck with this apparently simple problem. Any ideas?

*Edit*
The rank of the matrix is 4 and denoting by $R_i$ the $i$-th row of the matrix, $R_5=-R_2+R_3+R_4$ and $R_6=R_1-2R_2+R_3+R_4$.

The row-reduced form of the matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \\ 0&-1&1&1 \\ 1&-2&1&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you want to find all such $a,b,c,d$, or will you settle for one (assuming, of course, that such exists)?

Comment: @gerrymyerson Well in the end all of them but I may be able to extrapolate from one solution by myself. I don't see how to tackle the problem.

Comment: OK. Have you tried using row-reduction to find a basis for the column space of that matrix?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I added the expression of the last two rows as functions of the first four (which are linearly independent). Is this what you suggested?

Comment: No. What I suggested was "using row-reduction to find a basis for the column space of that matrix."

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK, I added it. Every time I solve "two elements of $[a,b,c,d,-b+c+d,a-2b+c+d]$ are equal", I end up with the equality of two elements of ${a,b,c,d}$. I'd like to prove that there is no other solution, or find such other solutions.

Comment: OK, it's harder than I thought. There are solutions, e.g., $(a,b,c,d)=(-3,1,0,2)$ leads to $(2,2,0,6,4,4)$. But there are 65 ways for $V$ to have exactly 4 different components, and I think you'd have to check them all to get the complete solution.

Comment: So, how are we doing?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I added an answer with the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not manage to find an elegant way to solve this problem, I solved it systematically. In each step I solved $V_i=V_j$ and $V_k=V_l$ with $(i,j)$ and $(k,l)$ different subsets of $\{(2,1), (3,1),\dots,(6,5)\}$.

Deleting all the duplicates, what I finally obtained is (the "$\to$" are to be interpreted as "$=$"):
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \{\{b\to 0,c\to 0\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to 0,d\to 0\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to 0,d\to b\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to 0,d\to -b\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to 0\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to b,d\to -b\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to b,d\to 0\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to b,d\to b\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to b,d\to 2 b\}\} \\
 \{\{b\to 0,d\to -c\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to -b,d\to b\}\} \\
 \left\{\left\{c\to -\frac{b}{2},d\to \frac{b}{2}\right\}\right\} \\
 \{\{c\to 2 b,d\to -b\}\} \\
 \left\{\left\{c\to \frac{b}{2},d\to \frac{b}{2}\right\}\right\} \\
 \{\{c\to -b,d\to 2 b\}\} \\
 \{\{b\to 0,d\to 0\}\} \\
 \{\{d\to b\}\} \\
 \{\{b\to 0,d\to c\}\} \\
 \{\{b\to 0\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to -b,d\to 0\}\} \\
 \{\{d\to 0\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to -2 b,d\to -b\}\} \\
 \{\{c\to -b,d\to -b\}\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

If I restrict these values to positive values, and add the condition that all $a,b,c,d$ should be all different, nothing is left. That answers my question but I am still interested, out of curiosity, in a more elegant way to find this.

Comment: 1. There was nothing in your question about non-negative values. 2. There's another way for $V$ to have exactly 4 different coordinates, namely, for three coordinates to be equal, and the other three to be different. 3. What if $(a,b,c,d)=(7,1,0,2)$? $a,b,c,d$ are all different, and all non-negative.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 1. That's a remark in the answer. 2. Yes, that corresponds to the cases $V_2=V_1$ and $V_3=V_1$, and my answer considers such cases. 3. I meant positive ($>0$), language confusion, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one answer: if $(a,b,c,d)=(-3,1,0,2)$, then $V=(2,2,0,6,4,4)$. As I noted in the comments, I think finding all the solutions would entail looking at a large number of cases.

EDIT: It's clear that $(a,b,c,d)=(a,1,0,2)$ works as long as $a$ is not one of the numbers $0,1,2$.

Comment: You solution indeed corresponds to $\{c\to 0\}$ in my freshly-posted answer.